# Postgres 9.4 importing csv file causes connection abort

Tags: postgresql-9.4, import, csv

I have very simple database which i would like to import data from a csv file, so far i tested with a file with a few rows, and it worked.

So tried to upload the real data to the database, which causes this error:

```
Software caused connection abort (0x00002745/10053)
```

And this error message too:

```
Copy failed!
Connection to database broken.
```

Now i have done this before, i have uploaded way more bigger csv files into the database with no problem, my file is roughly about 1.4 Mb.

Note: i'm connected to the database via ssh tunnel, although this should be not a problem.

Why i'm losing the connection? i have checked that i have permission to modify the csv files